# How to print the value in the official version of tf2.0.0?

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7

I found that I can't display the value of tensor in the official version of tf2.0.0. What should I do? numpy? eval?

```
print(tf.random.uniform((3, 3)))

print(tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(tf.random.uniform((3, 3))))
```

The result:

```
Tensor("random_uniform:0", shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)

Tensor("layer_normalization/batchnorm/add_1:0", shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure of your TF version? Here is my result for your code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def main():
    print("Version: ", tf.version.VERSION)
    print(tf.random.uniform((3, 3)))
    print(tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(tf.random.uniform((3, 3))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Version:  2.0.0
tf.Tensor(
[[0.4394927  0.44767535 0.02136886]
 [0.7118287  0.65160227 0.47469318]
 [0.7066748  0.130373   0.09051967]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.8090544  -1.4032681   0.5942137 ]
 [-1.3625047   0.38342142  0.9790828 ]
 [-1.2024965   0.00880218  1.1936939 ]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

You also have the choice to use `tf.print` instead of `print` which displays only the values (not the shape, nor the data type), which is the same as calling `print(tensor.numpy())`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, my version is inexplicably changed to 1.14.0, but my pipfile is 2.0.0.(＃－.－）